# Why does @gringer have a wiki tag?

Tags: discussion

Whilst editing the sites wiki tags I noted that @gringer was listed, alongside including formal technical nomenclature such as population genetics, allele frequencies, haplotype networks, synonymous mutations etc.... I duely filled in the @gringer wiki tag as best I understood it, but was left puzzled ... is there a greater meaning here that has escaped me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like [you added it](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/posts/654/revisions) a few months ago. Perhaps by accident; you might have tried to [ping](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) them in a comment but didn't realize you were typing in the tag box.

I've suggested an edit to remove the tag, as indeed users shouldn't have their own tag (you can't be an expert in 'gringer'). One of the co-founders of Stack Exchange has [his own tag on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jeff-atwood) but that's a reasonable exception.

Comment: Ah okay ... yes I probably did